# Adding Model file to view controller, help getting UI working

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I wrote a Model file for my basic app and I'm in the process of applying the model to the UI. It has 3 manual inputs and a text area for the "results" once the calculate button has been pressed.

I'm really struggling with making the UI do what I want it to do, I just want the results displaying, I tried `print()` but get unresolved identifiers in view controller.

How do I get the .value of my results from the Model file in the view controller? Or have to initialize those again?

Model File (Struct)

```
struct FuelMaths {

var rate: Double = 3.7 //set initialValvue
var tank: Int = 110
var laps: Int = 13
var totalFuel: Double
var totalStops: Double

init (rate: Double, tank: Int, laps: Int) {
    self.rate = rate // declare an instance
    self.tank = tank
    self.laps = laps
    totalFuel = rate * Double(laps)
    totalStops = totalFuel / Double(tank)
}

func result () {

    print(totalFuel.value)
    print(totalStops.value)
}

}
```

View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var rate: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var laps: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tank: UITextField!
    let calculate = FuelMaths(rate: 3.7, tank: 110, laps: 13)

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func calculate(sender: UIButton) {



    }
    @IBOutlet weak var display: UITextView!

}
```

Thanks all.

Comment: cheers for the reply, do you mean result function in model file to return value then call that in my view controller in result func ? Sorry I'm still quite new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Edit: I originally said you didn't instantiate the model at class scope; you did, but you misnamed it as a verb `calculate` rather than a good noun like `fuelCalculationModel`. But anyway, I'm using it the way you've written it: which is as sort of a one-off where the values are passed in at construction time and those values are assumed final so that the result is calculated immediately. It is possible to write a model that is designed to persist and adjust to changes in its source value over time, but you need to understand property observers or computed properties for that.)

See if the solution is helpful:

```
@IBAction func calculate(sender: UIButton) {
    if let rateVal = Double(rate.text!),
           tankVal = Int(tank.text!),
           lapVal = Int(laps.text!) {
        let fuelModel = FuelMaths(rate: rateVal, tank: tankVal, laps: lapVal)
        display.text = "Total fuel: \(fuelModel.totalFuel) Total Stops: \(fuelModel.totalStops)"
    }
    else {
        display.text = "One of the text fields did not have a valid number."
    }
}
```

Ultimately you want the model to be a persistent object at class-level scope, not function scope, and you want it to recalculate its results whenever its source values are changed, but wait on that until you understand this, especially if-let when constructing numbers out of parsed Strings.

Comment: Cheers for the reply, this appears more like the results I'm after. I've added your suggestion to my View Controller however I get a "Unresolved identifier" for "fuelModel" just amended too "Let fuelModel = ....." and it appears to work. Thanks need to fix my layout issues and I'm sure it will run

Comment: I forgot the `let` originally on that

Comment: Thank you again, I will use the code you supplied to understand whats going on. Thank you again. Now layout......